# how to choose an item as selected and toggle others to unselected?

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

I have 3 button in a row like these :
button 1    button 2    button 3
and I want just the text of selected one bolded.
for example :
button 1    button 2    **button 3**
what's the best and easiest way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a variable to hold the current button thats selected. Then based on that you can switch the fontWeight like the following

```dart
int selectedButton = 0;

Row(
 children:List.generate(3, (index) {
   return InkWell(
    onTap:(){
      setState((){selectedButton = index;});
    },
    child: Text("button $index", style: TextStyle(
     fontWeight : selectedIndex == index ? FontWeight.w900: FontWeight.w400,
    ))
   )
 })
)
```